# How to duplicate a wordpress user and all his/her data from custom fields?

Tags: users, duplicates

I have many user profiles with a lot of data via custom fields, and have to add it manually. I am wondering how to duplicate users, and then modify some of the data to speed up the process.

For what I see most of solutions is to avoid duplicated users.

Comment: Programatically, or with a UI?

Comment: With an UI preferably, having the option to duplicate in a button (for example) for other users to be able to manage.